# powershell to export all the outlook inbox emails to Excel file

Tags: powershell

I am writing a powershell script to export all the outlook-2013 inbox contents to a excel sheet. i tried many codes but I am getting error or irrelavent output. Kindly help.

Comment: Ramya, can you show what you tried in your last attempt and the relevant errors messages?

Comment: My code is Function Get-OutlookInBox 
{ 
 
 Add-type -assembly "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook" | out-null 
 $olFolders = "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.olDefaultFolders" -as [type]  
 $outlook = new-object -comobject outlook.application 
 $namespace = $outlook.GetNameSpace("MAPI") 
 $folder = $namespace.getDefaultFolder($olFolders::olFolderInBox) 
 $folder.items |  
 Select-Object  -Property Subject, ReceivedTime, SenderName , SenderAddress | Out-File XXXX\Trial.txt 
} 

$inbox = Get-OutlookInBox

Comment: my output is in text. But i want it in Excel and the Subject that I am getting is a piece.I want it completely. And the sender email Id is blank completely. I need it too

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for posting your code, as that enables me to help you. By changing the final line into  `$folders.items | Get-Member`, this lists all of the available properties which I don't see a `SenderAddress` but I do see `SenderEmailAddress`.

Secondly, you want output that you can open in Outlook with full details. Piping the final line with `Out-File` will send the data formatted as a table of strings. So instead let's use the `Export-CSV` cmdlet, to export it in a format that you can open in Excel. (Note that if you wanted to you could use some of the [Excel Modules](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2015/11/25/introducing-the-powershell-excel-module-2/) to pipe this out to an xlsx directly if you wanted.

Two sidenotes. You will still need to replace `XXXX/trial.csv` with the location you would like this to be saved. Be careful that when you run this, your PowerShell session elevation state matches Outlook. If PowerShell is Elevate/Run as administrator and Outlook is not, it won't work.

```
Function Get-OutlookInBox { 
    Add-Type -AssemblyName "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook" | out-null 
    $olFolders = "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.olDefaultFolders" -as [type]
    $Outlook = New-Object -ComObject Outlook.Application
    $Namespace = $Outlook.GetNameSpace("MAPI")
    $Folder = $Namespace.GetDefaultFolder($olFolders::olFolderInBox) 
    $Folder.Items | Select-Object -Property Subject, ReceivedTime, SenderName, SenderEmailAddress | Export-CSV -NoTypeInformation XXXX\Trial.csv 
}
```